# Try to start intent, if crash, start another intent

Tags: android, android-intent

I am developing an app were i need to use some sort of method to handel two different intents from a click of a Button. The first is only sometimes able to start without crashing the app. Therfore i need to start another intent were the app normally would have crashed.

Better explained do I need some sort of method that launches another intent, if the 1. intent can not start a new activity, then start the 2 intent.

I really appreciate some sort of formula, instead of a link or reference.

Comment: when is it crashing? (and why, too?) is it in the startIntent?

Comment: Are you not simply looking for try...catch?

Comment: If you're attempting to start an `Activity` and it fails and crashes then you're doing something wrong. What can cause the first `Activity` to fail to start - explain further. It seems to me you probably just need some pre-test or alternatively well structured exception handling.

Comment: It is an intent that is getting package names from SharedPreferences and then tries to launch them. If there are not any selected or if you have deleted the app, it then send you back to where you can select a new package name.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are looking for a try catch block.

```
try
{
     startActivity(intent);
}
catch(Exception e)
{
     startActivity(another_intent);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try/Catch in your code. You can then launch another intent if the first one fails.

If your application is crashing, you should sort this out. You wont be able to start another intent if the application crashes though, because the Applications Process has been killed by the OS. You will need to detect if you can launch the activity, otherwise launch another.

Comment: Can you make an example or some sort of formula? (I try to detect if you can launch the activity, otherwise launch another.)

Comment: It would be easier if you provide us a example of why your app would crash. Crashing is a bad UX, catching some functionality which is only available on some devices is the correct pattern, and performing another action when you have caught this is what you should be doing.

Answer (score 0):

Fix the crash, then implement some switching logic based on what used to be causing a crash.